# Efficiently sampling a uniform random matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, random

I need to sample a huge random matrix, whose size is `499 x 15500`, i.e. `7734500` elements. For this reason, I would like the sampling procedure to be as efficient as possible. At the moment, in a cpp file I am doing this:

```
std::random_device rd; // seed generator

std::mt19937_64 generator{rd()}; // generator initialized with seed from rd


std::uniform_int_distribution<> initialize(unsigned long long int modulus)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> unifDist{0, (int)(modulus-1)};
    return unifDist;
}


Matrix<unsigned int> uniformRandomMatrix
    (unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns, unsigned long long int modulus)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist = initialize(modulus);

    // Declare and allocate the matrix
    Matrix<unsigned int> matrix(rows, columns);
    // this constructor just does a resize on a std::vector

    // Fill the matrix with random elements
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        {
            matrix.setElementAt(i, j, dist(generator));
            // setElementAt just does matrix[somePosition] = newElement
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Note that a `Matrix` is implemented as a 1D `std::vector` for efficiency.

Can I do better than this? Right now, sampling this huge matrix takes approximately 0.16 seconds.

## EDIT using `std::vector::data`

The new approach is this: I added to the `Matrix` class a method

```
inline std::vector<T> exposeVector()
{
    return matrix;   // 'matrix' is the name of the private std::vector
}
```

Then to sample the uniform `Matrix`

```
Matrix<unsigned int> uniformRandomMatrix
    (unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns, unsigned long long int modulus)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist = initialize(modulus);

    // Declare and allocate the matrix
    Matrix<unsigned int> matrix(rows, columns);

    std::vector<unsigned int> v = matrix.exposeVector();
    unsigned int* p = v.data();

    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < rows*columns ; ++i)
    {
        *p = dist(generator);
        ++p;
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but I did not gain anything performance-wise.

Comment: Other engines might be faster than the mersenne twister. You could split the matrix (`std::vector`) into blocks and fill them in parallel. Make sure `Matrix` has a move constructor (because you're returning one and a copy could be avoided).

Comment: @Aleph Thank you for your suggestions! Actually I had not thought about changing engine: I will give it a try. I also understand that parallelizing the algorithm would make things faster, but I don't get what you said about move constructors... I don't think I have one right now

Comment: In my tests on my system the `64bit` version of the twister is somewhat slower than the normal `32bit` version. I see you allow for a large range for the modulus in your function  parameter but your distribution is being instantiated with the default `int`. Otherwise you may get some benefit from putting a back-door function in your matrix allowing access to the flat vector.

Comment: @Aleph Likely there's no copy occurring due to NRVO.

Comment: @Galik I see what you mean: I added that ugly cast to `int` just to get rid of a warning, but in principle I would like to allow for very large moduli. It's just that I don't know how to do it... As for the access to the flat vector, (if I understand correctly) this is what `setElementAt` does. Or maybe I am missing somthing...

Comment: The problem with `setElementAt` is that it requires nested for loops which will requires at lest two CPU registers to operate efficiently rather than one for a single for loop. Also you save yourself the calculation over the number of elements.

Comment: @Galik Okay, I see. I also tried to fill a normal `std::vector` and then use it to create a `Matrix` (I have a specific constructor for that) but it wasn't faster at all. Maybe `std::thread`s are the only option. Anyway I also tried the `32bit` version of the twister but it seems way slower (0.25 sec vs. 0.16 sec)

Comment: @Rostislav True, but we'd need more context to see if RVO is possible for all uses of `Matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty broad question in my opinion, but I'll try to give you a couple of pointers:

- First and probably the most obvious thing would be to do it in multiple threads `std::thred`
- If your Matrix is a derived class and your `setElementAt` is virtual, it's really expensive because of vtable resolving. Get rid of that (see next line)
- Usually compiler already does a lot of optimizations, but you may still try to minimize function/method calls, by exposing your [vector::data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) and iterating as a single Array `for(int i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++); data[i] = random` or try [std::generate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

Comment: Actually `Matrix` is not a derived class: it just wraps a `std::vector` and provides some operations (like addition, multiplication, etc.). Anyway I think I will have to move to a parallel implementation and use `std::thread`s. As for the `setElementAt`, it just does `matrix[row*numColumns + column] = elem;` but maybe I can try to invoke it less often

Comment: In that case using only single threaded access through vector::data might provide any performance increase, otherwise threads...

Comment: See the edit to the original post: I tried using `std::vector::data` (hopefully in the right way) but didn't gain anything. It seems threads is the way to go...